# What are the default assemblies loaded in dotnet (5 in particular)

Tags: c#, namespaces, ide, .net-5, assemblies

I am struggling to understand which assemblies are loaded by default and adding a using statement to its namespace is enough to use it, vs when the actual assembly is not being loaded.

Here is an example in VSCode as a picture is worth 1000 words.

[image]

As you can see, the compiler / IDE is hinting to me add the using statement to `System.Net.WebSockets`. The assembly this lives in is `System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll` living in the `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.17` folder (observed via ILSpy).

However, if I want to use for example `ServerWebSocket`, I dont get that help.

[image]

As you can see, the compiler has no idea what I am referring to, when in reality, I am referring to the `System.Net.HttpListener.dll` which lives in the same folder!

So my question is, what assemblies are there by default, and what need to be added manually?

Comment: There is no `ServerWebSocket` that I can see, apart from an `internal` class. Can you point to the docs for it?

Comment: You are right!. I was looking at the `internal` one. Thanks

Comment: But I would still like to know, are all those dlls in that folder included by default?

Comment: Not usually, but the IDE will offer them to you automatically if they are part of the .NET Framework